# {% trans "string" as my_translated_string %} is not rendering content in template

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, translation

Django 1.4 doc says that you can get translated strings into "vars" to be used in different places or to be used as arguments in template tags or filters using the following syntax:

```
{% trans "String" as my_translated_string %}

<h1>{{ my_translated_string }}</h1>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag

I'm doing it in that way, however the defined var is never rendering the content. Below my template code:

```
{% extends "default_layout.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% trans "My page title" as title %}

{% block meta_title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Of course "title" is being rendered empty in both cases.

Am I missing something ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to put `{% trans %}` inside `{% block meta_title %}`.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? If I use directly {% trans "My page title" %} into the block or the <h1> it works, but I'd like not to repeat the translation.

Answer (score 8):

As `okm` said you need to define the variable within the block in which you want to use it, and the scope of that variable is also within the block:

```
{% extends "default_layout.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block meta_title %}
{% trans "My page title" as title %}
{{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% trans "My page title" as title %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ohh, ok, it's clear now...so, it seems that for my needs this solution does not work and I'll have to repeat the text. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there really no way to store the result of the `trans ... as` tag into a variable with global scope inside the template? That would be helpful. The above solution is not DRY.

Comment: One way to solve the DRY issue is via setting a translated `title` value in the template `context` in the related view. -- Unfortunately, the fact that `trans ... as` doesn't work across blocks is not mentioned in the Django docs. I've [brought up this issue](https://github.com/django/django/commit/839edcebb39f55acf163266f1ce1f0dc537de95b#commitcomment-20449057) on GitHub.